# no stderr output when using stdbuf -o 0 |& tee log

Tags: io-redirection

I want to log the standard output and error info from running my program, using the following command:

```
  stdbuf -o 0 ./myprogram|& tee mylog
```

it works fine in one computer, I can see both standard output and stderr output on screen and in `mylog`.  but in another computer, I can only see the standard output in screen and `mylog`. They are both Fedora OS and x86_64.

Comment: Are you using the same shell on both machines?

Comment: Also, please rephrase your question to be a real question. Are you looking for working alternatives to your current command or are you looking to find out why that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making both stdout and stderr unbuffered.

```
stdbuf -e 0 -o 0 ./myprogram |& tee mylog
```

**Edit:** I replaced my original answer. The above is most likely a solution to the problem.

Comment: strange, with `stdbuf -o 0 ./myprogram 2>&1 | tee mylog`, the problem persists

Comment: I have added another possibility to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does for e.g.) then that will override corresponding settings changed by 'stdbuf'.

Please read it here; https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf